# "Import as" isn't recognized, normal import is

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, import

I'm playing around with matplotlib to understand its structure better and I'm confused by the following piece of code:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
from mpl import pyplot as plt # ModuleNotFoundError : No module named 'mpl'
mpl.pyplot # AttributeError: module 'matplotlib' has no attribute 'pyplot'
```

If on the other hand I abstain from importing matplotlib `as` a different name and execute instead

```
import matplotlib
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt #works!
```

the things work.

Even more crazy, if I "combine" these two
import matplotlib as mpl
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt #works!
mpl.pyplot.get_backend() # works

I can curiously access attributes from `pyplot` even if I reference it as `mpl.pyplot`.

What is going on here, why does

- `from mpl import pyplot as plt` throws a `ModuleNotFoundError`?
- `import mpl.pyplot` not work? Since the error message indcates that `mpl` was correctly resolved to `matplotlib`, yet still `pyplot` couldn't be found...
- referencing `pyplot` as `mpl.pyplot` not cause an error in my last example?

(Note that I do know of course that the preferred way is to import `pyplot` as `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` but the point of my investigation is precisely to understand what fails and why when I ventured outside the welltrodden streets of code.)

Comment: When you take a look at the [importlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html) documentation you can see that with your first example it's searching for a `mpl` package which doesn't exist

Comment: @chill0r I read through https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.import_module but I don't understand how that abstract definition relates to my examples, since no mentioning is made how the search for modules is actually conducted  ...

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. The import mechanism calls the Finders find_spec method with the package name (in your case `mpl` ) util a spec for the module is returned or all finders on sys.meta_path have been tried (fullname as string, later normally the same as `__name__` ). With this the finder (normally) just searches the sys.path for python classes / modules named that way. Once a finder has found and returned the spec the Loader will be called to create / execute the imported module itself.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I was able to read from here (https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#importsystem) a bit about how Finders and Loaders work and from here (https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-import-statement) the abstract syntax of the import module. I'm quoting from the latter: 1) "*If the module name is followed by `as`, then the name following `as` is bound directly to the imported module*" and 2) "*The `from` form uses a slightly more complex process: find the module specified in the `from` clause, loading and initializing it if necessary*".

Comment: Wouldn't 1) and 2) thus mean that in my code above that `mpl` is already "associated" to the `matplotlib` module and therefore using `from mpl [...]`, that `mpl` should be resolved to the `matplotlib` module?

Comment: (I have edited the question to emphasize this weird behavior of `import`.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `as` part in an import statement is just syntactic sugar for assigning the imported module to a variable with the given name. The [`import` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-import-statement) describes it as such:

> If the module name is followed by as, then the name following as is bound directly to the imported module.

"Bound" in this context means doing an assignment to the given name. The following statement

```
import someModule as someName
```

Is equivalent to this code:

```
import someModule
someName = someModule
```

So, when you do `import matplotlib as mpl`, all you do is create a variable called `mpl`. This has no effect on any further import statements, as import statements do not care about your local variables, but search for python packages and modules - and an `import as` statement cannot change the package or module name of the imported element. Which is a good thing, as you do not want your import statements to fail just because another import 5 lines earlier used a conflicting name in an `as` clause.

Now, why you're getting weird results with the `import mpl.pyplot` statement - no idea, it shouldn't work. You can see the expected behaviour if you try the following:

```
import os as asdf
import asdf.path    #ModuleNotFoundError: no module named 'asdf'
```

Tested with python 3.10.2 on Archlinux. If your example is reproducible, then you might have found a weird bug or undefined behaviour in your specific python version, or have some other issue (e.g. a `mpl` module in your path... although that on its own wouldn't explain why you get an error message about matplotlib instead of mpl).

In conclusion, all `as` does is assigning a name to the imported object, so a name assigned with `as` cannot be used as a source in another import statement.

---

On package imports and why `matplotlib.pyplot` gives an error:

Importing a package only imports the package itself, not any of its subpackages or modules. A package can explicitly import submodules in its `__init__.py`, so if the matplotlib init file would contain a statement like `from . import pyplot` line then accessing `matplotlib.pyplot` would work. There are however many reasons why a package might choose not to import any submodules, such as time and resources required to import and initialize them.

Comment: +1 "Bound" in this context means doing an assignment to the given name." & " import statements do not care about your local variables" this was spot on and finally clarified it for me, thanks!

Comment: Ah,I realized that my code had a small error, the command that lead to `AttributeError` was not `import mpl.pyplot` but rather just `mpl.pyplot` (the text must have gotten scrambled as I was copying, deleting & copying again code from my source file), so I needlessly confused myself even more. The behavior that actually was confusing was: Why is `mpl.pyplot` giving this error? (`matplotlib.pyplot` BTW gives the same error, so there's no bug here :) When I execute `from matplotlib import pyplot as plt` it works, yet I can't directly execute `matplotlib.pyplot`, which confuses me.

Comment: @user7088941 Ok, that explains it. Matplotlib is a package, and subpackages or modules of a package are not usually imported when you import the package itself, unless the `__init__.py` of the package explicitly triggers the import.

Answer (score 3):

Everything in python is a object, but when you import matplotlib you are importing all library but you cannot change your functions names, the library will looking for plt
`from matplotlib import pyplot as plt` in this case.
You can use plt directly but you cannot use mpl.plt.

When you tried it :

```
import matplotlib as mpl
from mpl import pyplot as plt # ModuleNotFoundError : No module named 'mpl'
mpl.pyplot
```

You should import correctly:

```
   import matplotlib as mpl
   from mpl import pyplot 
   mpl.pyplot
```

'As' change the module name what you going to use in your project, but not from another import.  But if you use plt directly it is going works.
Try this code to understand :

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib
print(type(matplotlib))
print(type(mpl))
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt# ModuleNotFoundError : No module named 'mpl'
from matplotlib import pyplot

print(type(plt))
print(type(mpl.pyplot))
plt
mpl.pyplot
```

Answer (score 2):

When you do `import module as mdl`, it doesn't change the module name. It only affects other statements when you actually use it. But the name doesn't change in the actual python lib or the external library. So what you can do is this:

```
import matplotlib
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
```

or just `from matplotlib import pyplot as plt`

This is my answer...

Comment: What are you using matplotlib for?

Comment: It would be more specific if you told us what your using it for.

Comment: And we can help you more